# about:blank#blocked on clicking open link in new tab

Tags: javascript, angular6

I am working on an angular 6 application in which I have a dropdown with some options in it. The options are nothing but a navigation routes. e.g home (/home), category (/category), etc,.
When I am clicking on the options the routing is happening as expected such as if I clicked on home it would navigated to /home page. But when I am clicking on the **open link in new tab** of the options (by right clicking on the option in chrome) the expected behavior should be opening of the page in new tab but instead of that I am getting **about:blank#blocked** page.

```
changeNavigationTab() {
    if (this.isRoutingRequired) {
        this.router.navigate(['/home'], { relativeTo: this.activatedRoute });
    } else {
        this.isRoutingRequired = true;
    }
}
```

Here changeNavigationTab() function gets called when I clicked on any option in the dropdown and navigate method is used to navigate the page to home page. (Here I have hardcoded /home but it will be coming from the mapping which I have created for option and routes.)

What I am looking for is after clicking on **open link in new tab** in chrome a new tab will be opened with home route.

I have tried :

```
const url = this.router.serializeUrl(this.router.createUrlTree(['/home']));
window.open(url, '_blank');
```

but it is working when someone clicks on the options and **about:blank#blocked** is still there after clicking on open link in new tab.